# Illustrator replace one path segment with another

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

Here I have 2 paths (second one highlighted in blue for emphasis:
[image: one path whose ends are in the same place as 2 points in the second path]

(that is, one path whose ends are in the same place as 2 points in the second path)

I want to get rid of the diagonal pink part below the blue part and replace it with the blue part so that the blue part is part of the whole pink path. I'm using Illustrator CC 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the red curve at the anchors with the scissors tool, remove the segment, place the blue part and finally join the parts (Ctrl+J)

I would add one anchor to the segment and drag it upwards with the direct selection tool. Then with the anchor type tool I would stretch the handles out of the node and fine tune the result with the direct selection tool:

[image]

Comment: Wow I figured it out myself and was about to answer my own question when you posted the exact same solution.

Comment: Always my compliments for your answers.